# Mongoose virtual population when foreignField is an object in the model

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I am trying to populate a virtual property with mongoose, which in my model is an object. I don't know how to target the foreignField.
I couldn't find any example, I'd appreciate any help :)

Favour model:

```
owner: {
        user: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            required: true,
            ref: 'User'
        },
        status: {
            type: String,
            default: null // In progress, Completed
        }
    },
```

User model where the virtual field is:

```
userSchema.virtual('favours', {
    ref: 'Favour',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: ?????
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!!

```
userSchema.virtual('favours', {
    ref: 'Favour',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'owner.user'
})
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.